# Need to remove the previous day plots in tradingview - pinescript

Tags: charts, pine-script

This is my code. Can you please update your answer in this bcz i tried and the indicator is not compiled properly.

//@version=3

study(title="TEST", overlay=true)

fib1 = security(tickerid,"D",high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

fib0 = security(tickerid,"D",low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plotS1 = input(title="Plot S1", type=bool, defval=true)

plotR1 = input(title="Plot R1", type=bool, defval=true)

R1 = (fib0-fib1)*0.215+fib1

S1 = (fib0-fib1)*0.79+fib1

plot(series=plotR1 ? R1 : na, title="R1", style=cross, linewidth=1, color=#EEC900) plot(series=plotS1 ? S1 : na, title="S1", style=cross, linewidth=1, color=#EEC900)

Answer (score 2):

```
//@version=4
study("Fib", "FiB", true)

[fib1,fib0] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high[2], low[2]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

is_today = year == year(timenow) and month == month(timenow) and dayofmonth == dayofmonth(timenow)

plot(fib0, "fib0", is_today ? color.green : na)
plot(fib1, "fib1", is_today ? color.blue  : na)
```